# Extensions of Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

I am looking for an answer to the following questions:

Are there infinite-dimensional Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ for which there are non-split extensions $0 \to X \to E_1  \to Y \to 0$ and $0 \to X \to E_2  \to Y \to 0$ such that $X$ is complemented in $E_1$ but non-complemented in $E_2$?

Also, let $\Delta \subset X \times X$ be the diagonal. Is $\Delta$ complemented in $X \times X$? Is the extension $ 0 \to \Delta \to X \times X \to  X \times X/{\Delta} \to 0 $ split-exact?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the questions for the following reason: if $X$ is complemented in $E_1$ then the extension is necessarily split by the open mapping theorem.

First question: If you're asking about a pair of extensions of $Y$ by $X$ with $E_1$ split and $E_2$ non-split, take $X = c_0$ and $Y = \ell^{\infty}/c_0$. Then $0 \to X \to \ell^{\infty} \to Y \to 0$ is not split by Phillips' lemma, and $0 \to X \to X \times Y \to Y \to 0$ is split by definition.

Second question: yes, $(x, y) \to \left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y), \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right)$ is a projection of $X \times X$ onto $\Delta$.

Comment: Yemon: Okay, done. It initially was an answer, but I then decided to move it to the comments because I was unsure how the community would react, as this question is barely "research level". I tried to supplement the comment with a bit of information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand the questions for the following reason: If the image of $X$ is complemented in $E_1$ then the extension is split. Indeed, if $P$ is a projection of $E_1$ onto the image of $X$ then $1-P$ is a projection onto an isomorph of $Y$ by the open mapping theorem (see e.g. [Nicolas Monod's thesis](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/b80626) Corollary 4.2.4 for a detailed proof).

First question: If you're asking about a pair of extensions of $Y$ by $X$ with $E_1$ split and $E_2$ non-split, take $X = c_0$ and $Y = \ell^{\infty}/c_0$. Then $E_2: 0 \to X \to \ell^{\infty} \to Y \to 0$ is not split by Phillips' lemma (see [Whitley's note](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2315346) in the Monthly for a simple proof), and $E_1: 0 \to X \to X \oplus Y \to Y \to 0$ is split by definition.

Second question: Yes, $(x, y) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y), \frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right)$ is a projection of $X \oplus X$ onto $\Delta$. I recommend you to prove that this sequence is isomorphic to the obvious extension $0 \to X \to X \oplus X \to X \to 0$ (inclusion into the first summand, projection onto the second).

Two final remarks:

- A very interesting procedure for producing non-split extensions of Banach spaces is the *twisted sum construction* due to [Kalton-Peck](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=542869) (I recently learned about this from Bill Johnson in [this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66345/example-of-a-compact-set-that-isnt-the-spectrum-of-an-operator)).
- Basically, you're asking about the [Yoneda Exts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Ext_and_extensions) in the [exact category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_category) of Banach spaces with the exact structure consisting of all kernel-cokernel pairs. If you're interested in such abstract nonsense, please allow me a bit of [self-advertisement](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2009.04.004).